# Python import from parent package

Tags: python, python-import

I'm having some trouble with imports in Python.

Here is a simple example of what's going wrong.

I have a directory structure like this:

```
app
|---__init__.py
|---sub_app
    |---__init__.py
```

The code:

app/__init__.py

```
shared_data = {
    'data': 123
}

from sub_app import more_shared_data
print more_shared_data
```

app/sub_app/__init__.py

```
more_shared_data = {
    'data': '12345'
}
from app import shared_data
print shared_data
```

However I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named app
```

How do I import the shared_data dict, into app/sub_app/__init__.py?

Comment: Have you looked at intra-package imports? Alternatively, refactor your package to avoid the issue.

Comment: refactor my package to what?

Comment: Don't put shared data at the top level, move it into a sub-module n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) for this . Example -

In your `app/sub_app/__init__.py` -

```
more_shared_data = {
    'data': '12345'
}
from .. import shared_data
print shared_data
```

This should work for the simple example you have provided , but it does lead to circular import , `app` is importing `sub_app` and `sub_app` is importing `app` .

For more complex usecases, you can end up with errors (If you import sub_app) before defining specific elements, and then in `sub_app/__init__.py` you try to import app and use those elements that are only defined after the import statement for `sub_app` . A very simple example where it would cause issue -

`app/__init__.py` -

```
from .sub_app import more_shared_data
print(more_shared_data)

shared_data = {
    'data': 123
}
```

`app/sub_app/__init__.py` -

```
more_shared_data = {
    'data': '12345'
}
from .. import shared_data
print(shared_data)
```

Now, if you try to import `app` , you will get the error -

```
>>> import app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<some file>\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .shared import more_shared_data
  File "<some file>\sub_app\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .. import shared_data
ImportError: cannot import name 'shared_data'
```

---

You should re-think if `shared_data` does belong to `app/__init__.py` , or it can be moved to `sub_app/__init__.py` and then imported from there in `app` .

Comment: from .. import shared_data gives the error ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package

Comment: What are you running? Apparently you are either running `Python` from within `sub_app` or directly running a file in it, if so, you cannot use relative import. I thought `sub_app` was only a sub package inside app?

Comment: You're right I was running it from inside sub_app, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems here, one of which is hidden.

It looks like you are trying to invoke your program like:

```
python app/__init__.py
python app/sub_app/__init__.py
```

This causes problems in that the directory of the main file is considered to be the root directory of the program. That is, why `sub_app` cannot see `app`.

You can instead invoke your programs like such

```
python -m app.sub_app
```

This way python assumed the current directory is the root directory and looks for the module `app.sub_app` under this directory. This causes another problem though. To be able to run a package you need to provide a `__main__.py` in the package (as well as `__init__.py`). If the modules do not import each other, then order of invocation will be `app/__init__.py`, `app/sub_app/__init__.py`, and then `app/sub_app/__main__.py`

```
app
|---__init__.py
|---sub_app
    |---__init__.py
    |---__main__.py
```

`app/sub_app/__main__.py` can do stuff like:

```
from app import shared_data
from . import more_shared_data
# or
from app.sub_app import more_shared_data
```

Finally, the hidden problem is that you have circular imports. That is, `app` depends on `sub_app` and `sub_app` depends on `app`. That both `app` and `sub_app` need the other to be loaded, before they can load -- this is of course impossible. You should refactor your code to avoid circular imports.