# Stuck at reusing code from parent package in Python

Tags: python

I have a bunch of scripts for static code analysis.

The get a directory as the command line argument, and they run on all files inside that directory.

Here's the structure of my project:

```
__init__.py
run.py
message.py
globals.py
react
    __init__.py
    run.py
    check_imports.py
    analyze_states.py
next
    __init__.py
    check_routes.py
    analyze_images.py
git
   __init__.py
   check_size.py
   ensure_branch_name.py
   run.py => how can I call this and still access message.py?
```

Now, if I use top-level `run.py` as the orchestrator to call sub-modules inside sub-packages, everything works great and I can use `import message` from each sub-module.

But for `git` package, I want to call it directly. And I want to use functions defined inside `message.py`. I'm stuck at this point.

I saw [Python import from parent package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563824/python-import-from-parent-package) and tried `from .. import message` but it does not work.

Comment: try running it from parent foldeer, like `python3 parentfolder/git/run.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I did find out is for the git parent folder to be in your python path.
In general when I am developing I would add this lines in your `git/run.py`

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
```

Then you will be able to `import message`

When you finish with development and it is ready for `pip install` you need to make sure that message is an importable module in your `setup.py` for example.

**Update**

The '..' will only work if you execute the `git/run.py` script or module from within the `git` repository as '..' is a relative path.

If you want to execute `run.py` from anywhere you can do:

```
import os
import sys

parent_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(parent_dir)
```

Just have in mind that `__file__` will only exist if you execute `run.py` in batch mode **not from an interactive shell or a notebook**.

Comment: I tested this. But it did not work. Even during the development it did not work. I had to change it to `sys.path.append('full-absolute-path-to-parent-here')` to make it work.

Comment: That may be because you execute `run.py` from outside the `git` directory. Also some OS may not accept the '..' notation. See my update above. Basically what you need is to make sure that the parent directory of `git`, where the message.py module is located, is in your PYTHONPATH.